# Designdata with xaml and class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class ComponentItem which i simplified (pseudo code) below

```
public class ComponentItem : NotificationObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _files;
    public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files

    private ObservableCollection<SparepartItem> spareparts;
    public ObservableCollection<SparepartItem> SpareParts
    public string ObjectId
}
```

If i create design data for this class i can do it by

```
<m:ComponentItem xmlns:m="clr-namespace:AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models;assembly=AITReportEditor.Infrastructure" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDD">
    <m:ComponentItem.PartData>
        <m:PartDataItem Name="Component name" Status="1" Note="This is a note description"  />   
    </m:ComponentItem.PartData>
    <m:ComponentItem.Files>
        <m:FileItem FileName="Image1.jpg" Note="This is a note1" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDD" ></m:FileItem>
        <m:FileItem FileName="Image1.jpg" Note="This is a note2" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDE" ></m:FileItem>
    </m:ComponentItem.Files>
    <m:ComponentItem.SpareParts>
        <m:SparepartItem ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDD" Note="This is a note1" SpId="1" Amount="22" />
        <m:SparepartItem ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDE" Note="This is a note2" SpId="1" Amount="23" />
    </m:ComponentItem.SpareParts>
</m:ComponentItem>
```

I can use this as design data for a usercontro. The user control contains custom child usercontrols and the design data does not show in the child controls when i design the parent so i want to add design data to the child controls seperately. My problem is that i cant seem to define the xaml for just a collection like the

private ObservableCollection _files;

there seems to be no way of declaring like , pseudo xaml code

```
<List<FileItem>  ............
 <m:FileItem ...... />
```

I solved it by declaring an unessesary class FilesItem

```
 public class FilesItem : ObservableCollection<FileItem>
    {
        public FilesItem()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and xaml file.

```
<m:FilesItem xmlns:m="clr-namespace:AITReportEditor.Infrastructure.Models;assembly=AITReportEditor.Infrastructure">
    <m:FileItem FileName="Image1.jpg" Note="This is a note1" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDD" ></m:FileItem>
    <m:FileItem FileName="Image2.jpg" Note="This is a note2" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDE" ></m:FileItem>
    <m:FileItem FileName="Image2.jpg" Note="This is a note2" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDF" ></m:FileItem>
</m:FilesItem>
```

Anyone know if this is the way to do it or can i somehow get rid of the unessesary classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create generic instances in XAML (at least in compiled XAML), one workaround is subclassing as you showed. Another method would be to delegate the creation to a markup extension, something like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class GenericCollectionFactoryExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Type> _TypeArguments = new List<Type>();
    public List<Type> TypeArguments { get { return _TypeArguments; } }

    private readonly List<Object> _Items = new List<Object>();
    public List<Object> Items { get { return _Items; } }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var genericType = Type.MakeGenericType(_TypeArguments.ToArray());
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType) as IList;
        if (list == null) throw new Exception("Instance type does not implement IList");
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

This creates the generic collection using reflection, adds all the items passed to it (here it assumes that an `IList` will be created to make it easier) and returns the collection.

Usage:

```
xmlns:om="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System"
```

```xml
<me:GenericCollectionFactory x:Key="files"
                Type="{x:Type om:ObservableCollection`1}">
    <me:GenericCollectionFactory.TypeArguments>
        <x:Type Type="m:FileItem" />
    </me:GenericCollectionFactory.TypeArguments>
    <m:FileItem FileName="Image1.jpg" Note="This is a note1" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDD" />
    <m:FileItem FileName="Image1.jpg" Note="This is a note2" ObjectId="AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDDE" />
</me:GenericCollectionFactory>
<!-- ... -->
<m:ComponentItem Files="{StaticResource files}"/>
```

The `` `1 `` is necessary to specify that this type is generic. You could cut down on the XAML by creating a version which only takes one type-argument (as many classes like `ObservableCollection` only have one), saves three lines.

Comment: Glad that helped, i had quite fight with this one.